# add translation in rumtime for gettext

Tags: c++, linux, gettext

I'm using gettext to translate some messages in C/C++ program.
In the program, some translations are user definable so they may be changed while it's running.
Is it possible to update gettext database in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question whether you want the translations to change while the program is actually running, or whether you merely mean that the translations may change after the program is already compiled.

If you mean the later, there is nothing you need to do. That is simply how gettext works. You create the core database, and then plug in translations as distinct files.

If you actually literally mean the former, there is no way to do it. `gettext` does not guarantee how the actual translations are loaded, and it is not safe to replace the translation database at runtime, just like that.

What might be possible to do is, if the program is aware that the translations might change, is to manually flush the database and reload it. Calling `textdomain`(3) to switch to another text domain and then back might reload the database.

Comment: Yes, I mean the former one. I think you mean that I have to create mo file on demand and reload it. I think it is one possible way but I wanted to know if there is some way to update the database from C api. Thanks for the answer anyway.